# Google App Script create a hyperlink to the current cursor position inside a Google document

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-api-client, google-docs-api

I am trying to create a script that lets me to create hyperlink at the position of the cursor in a google document. And then send an email which body contains the link to the specific email address.

I know I can access the cursor position at DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor(); and I know I can create a bookmark using the Bookmark Class. But I cannot find any reference or api to let me create either the link of the bookmark or at the position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you : D